# How to write a shell script to run multiple command in different screen sessions?

Tags: shell-script, zsh, gnu-screen

My goal is to write a `zsh` script in order to create multiple `screen` sessions and run separate commands on each of them. I would also like to check at the beginning of my script if there are any screens with running jobs and terminate all of them that sit idle. Furthermore, if possible I would like to have a way to record the stdout of the individual screen and get their ID number. So far I have tried the following:

```
### Script for running everything in screens ###
killall -15 screen ## We make sure that no screens are running for now
#bkg_array = ("TopJets" "BosonJets" "DiBoson" "TTbar")

screen -dmS "MYSCREEN"
screen -S "MYSCREEN" -p 0 -X stuff 'echo "The array has of elements."\n'
```

However, I cannot seem to send the keystroke for pressing `Enter`; how can I achieve that effect? Additionally without the `-p` option the command is not sent to the screen. After pressing <kbd>Ctrl+V+Enter</kbd> the characters `^M` were pasted on the screen and it pressed enter in the screen session, but I have no idea why that worked.

Thanks for your help, feel free to point out any ambiguities.

Comment: instead of making problem, use `tmux`

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh Thanks, but `tmux` is not installed on the machine I am running the shell script on and I have no administrator privileges on the computer.

Comment: Forget `tmux`and forget `screen`. Just use `zpty`. Youll automatically get that array you want. Combine that with `ztcp` and youve got remote access.

Comment: Do `man zsh-modules` for information on both. Else, [look here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147336/52934) for a simple-minded `zpty` demo.

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks for the answer, but I am not experienced with zpty and when I type it in the command prompt nothing appears. And is it not possible to define an array in plain zsh?

Comment: @Vesnog - of course it is, but you have to define it. Just using `zpty` automatically does this - as soon as it is used once it creates an array and tracks each opened `zpty` process within. There is also a `screen` convenience function that comes with `zsh`. Do `autoload screen; zed -f screen` to have a look at it. Oh - and I was wrong before - you want to do `man zshmodules` - no hyphen.

Comment: You're sending an LF character, which bash and zsh as well as the tty line editor (with default bindings) treat like CR which is the character sent by the Enter key. What is received inside the screen window (attach the screen to look)?

Comment: @Gilles When I sent `\n` and attached the screen to check the process I saw that the command has been entered like command/n and the enter key was to pressed in order for the screen to execute it. I tried pressing `Ctrl+V+Enter` as in another post here and the characters `^M` was printed inside the script file, and the screen interpreted that as LF character. However, I have no idea why that worked.

Answer (score 1):

I find that while screen doesn't interpret named characters such as `\n`, it does take care of octal escapes. So instead of `stuff 'echo "The array has of elements."\n'`, you could use:

```
stuff 'echo "The array has of elements."'\012
```

Answer (score 0):

So what I do is this:

> screen -dmS SCREEN_SESSION_NAME -t TAB_NAME ~/bin/my_first_prog.sh ; screen -S SCREEN_SESSION_NAME -X screen -t TAB_NAME2 ~/bin/my_second_prog.sh

At the the you will have a screen session, called SCREEN_SESSION_NAME,  with two tabs.
To exit from everything 
I kill the programs gracefully ( kill -1 ) and the run

> screen -S SCREEN_SESSION_NAME -X quit